# Clever complete of .c and .o

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I would like that bash completes my command `vim myPr`<kbd>Tab</kbd> to `vim myProgramName.c` *even* if the current folder also contains a file called `myProgramName.o`, since 99.9% of the time I want to open the source with vim not the executable.

When executing this works very well: `./myP`<kbd>Tab</kbd> gets completed to `./myProgramName.o`. I would prefer if this stayed the way it is.

How can I achieve to automatically complete to `*.c` except when executing with `./…`?

Comment: In ZSH, this is done with something like `zstyle ':completion:*:*:(diff|*grep|less|vi|vim):*:all-files' ignored-patterns '*.core' '*.o' '*.midi'` to ignore certain patterns from text-reading programs.

Comment: @thrig I'm using bash at the moment, do you know any way how to achieve a similar effect in bash?

Answer (score 1):

This stuff is defined in your `bash_completion` script. Sometimes you can find that in `/etc` and sometimes in `/usr/share/bash-completion`.

Mine has this line:

```
_install_xspec '*.@([ao]|so|so.!(conf|*/*)|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class)' vi vim gvim rvim view rview rgvim rgview gview emacs xemacs sxemacs kate kwrite
```

It does exactly what you want.

I imagine your installation is too old. You can try updating "bash-completion", or editing that file yourself.

Alternatively, you could have your `.bashrc` edit the `_xspecs` variable manually -- bash-completion does not provide an interface to do this for you.

Edit: it turns out the OP was not using the bash-completion package at all (so just using the built-in "dumb" filename completion). In that case installing it and following the setup instructions is sufficient. On Linux this package is typically installed by default, and no user setup is required.

Comment: Okay, I since I'm on a mac I downloaded bash-completion via brew. Where do I need to put the script now? Do I need to create a specific file in `/usr/share/bash-completion/`? And how does it get sourced?

Comment: If you didn't have bash-completion before then you probably don't need to modify it at all. You should source it in your .bashrc file, but you might find the system bashrc already did.

Comment: Ok, I created a file *completion.sh* in */usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d*. That's where the installation description told me to put scripts. This file now contains your line, but I get `-bash: _install_xspec: command not found` on start-up. Any idea?

Comment: Don't bother. If you have a new version of bash-completion the rule is already there.

Comment: You just need to make sure that bash-completion is enabled in your shell.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Now I'll need to check how to enable bash-completion in *Terminal.app*?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37031/discussion-between-lastsecondstolive-and-ams).

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive Bewarre that OSX ships with an outdated version of bash. I'm not sure if bash-completion runs on that old version. I suggest switching to zsh, which has more powerful completion and is still being updated on OSX. If you want to stick to bash, you may need to use a third-party package (e.g. brew) for bash itself.

Comment: @Gilles Ok, I'll consider zsh.